# Dictionary task. Choose needed ones and order them

Tags: python, function, dictionary, web

stackoverfollowers!

There is a task that i am trying to resolve now. here it is:

> '' Write a function **samewords(u1, u2, enc, k)** that:
>
> 1. Take 2 urls and enc = ‘utf8’:
>      u1 = 'http://...u1..'
>      u2 =
>      'http://...u2...'
> 2. On this web pages u1 and u2 find words of the **length k** that occur on both pages
> 3. Count how many times that words occur on each page
> 4. **Return a list** that contain groups of 3 parameters: **word** (found in paragraph 2), **occur1** (how many times a word occurs on the page u1), **occur2** (how
>      many times a word occurs on the page u2)
> 5. A returned list should be in decreasing ordered in accordance with total number of occurs on the both pages ''

using this code to delete all notalphabetic characters

```
def mywords(s):              # delet nonalphabetic characters
    for c in '''!?/-,():;--'.\_[]"{}''':
        s = s.replace(c, ' ')
    return s.split()            # return a list of all words from page with my url

import urllib.request as ul

def myurl(u, enc):      #open my url
    p = ul.urlopen(u)
    t = p.read()
    p.close()

    return mywords(t.lower())
```

And then i meet difficultes with points 3-5 and stuck (mainly because if something doesn't go i check the code online with **pythontutor.com** but in this case i can't do that because it doesn't support urllib library)

Thank you!!!

Comment: replaceing non alphabetic can be `s = re.sub('\W' ,'', s)`

Comment: @Uriel How did I never think of this, what the actual. Thanks so much, +1!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @lucasdavid , i have this error TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not int  in the place when i check for nonalphabetic symbols so i can't go further

Comment: Or like this     TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'   for                 s = s.replace(c, ' ')

Comment: That's definitely weird, considering I copy/pasted this code in py2 and py3 interpreters and they both worked. Nonetheless, a work-around is to use @Krazor alternative to `mywords(s)` function: `re.sub('\W', ' ', s).lower().split()`

Comment: @lucaadavid It was not mine, reread comments!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need a test environment.
I would install Python on local machine and test code within IDLE, an editor that ships with Python.

Some ideas regarding your homework.
1. Function myurl reads the content of a remote html file as it were just a file.
You can put your code between the read() and the close() statement. You may walk through the file line by line and then word by word to find words that match your needs. You may want to remove unwanted chars from the word first by using function mywords.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what's is that you are having problem with, but I made a program that fits the specifications and it might serve as a base for you. However, you SHOULD definitely make your own implementation after understanding this.

Okay, first: the urllib api changes drastically from python 2 to 3. The HTMLParser class is also in different places depending on the version. That means you would have to do some additional work if you wanted your code to be portable. Going in a different direction, I chose to hide these problems by using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) to request the pages and [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse their content.
This is a trade-off, obviously, because you have to install non-native libraries:

*In your shell:*

```
$ pip install requests beautifulsoup4
```

The upside is that the code becomes very short:

*webpage_words_counter_example.py:*

```
import re
from collections import Counter

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def get_words_from_url(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    for script in soup(["script", "style"]):
        script.extract()
    # returns a list of words.
    return re.sub('\W', ' ', soup.get_text()).lower().split()


def samewords(u1, u2, enc, k):
    # Retrieve content, filter words with specified 
    # length and initialize repetition counters.
    w1, w2 = map(Counter,
                 (filter(lambda word: len(word) == k, words)
                  for words in map(get_words_from_url,
                                   (u1, u2))))

    # Map all words to a list of tuples (word, count_w1, count_w2)
    # and sort this list by count_w1 and count_w2.
    return sorted(map(lambda x: (x, w1[x], w2[x]),
                      set(w1.keys()) | set(w2.keys())),
                  # disregard the word itself when sorting,
                  # considering only its occurrence in each text.
                  key=lambda x: x[1:],
                  # reversed array, so most frequent words come first.
                  reverse=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_count = samewords(
        'https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/oct/27/scheme-to-reopen-river-severn-to-fish-wins-almost-20m-in-funding',
        'https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/oct/27/world-on-track-to-lose-two-thirds-of-wild-animals-by-2020-major-report-warns',
        'utf-8',
        10
    )

    print('word count:', word_count)
```